# Draw Bar/Column Chart using google app script

Tags: javascript, charts, google-apps-script

I want to draw a chart as presented in the image using the data.

Please follow the link for image : 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8FL6hHjH8poakoxRlFDVWRuams/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried searching?

Comment: Yes, I'm searching for other Java script libraries as well.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, there are a ridiculous number of chart API's out there which may or may not suit your needs, personally I would go with the [Google Charts API](https://developers.google.com/chart/) as it can accept multiple dataTypes and custom styles and you'll want to be looking for the column chart within the Google API Documentation.

Read the Documentation carefully or you will get lost on this one.
(Although this statement pretty much counts for anything with a documentation).

Comment: Hi Raptus, Its possible to create a columnChart or bar chart but till now it accept first column as string and rest all column as numbers.

Please go through the link described below:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/column-chart-builder

Comment: Have you read all of the documentation and formatting options within the Google Charts API? That result is as expected, I'm not sure what you're point is with the last comment.

Comment: I have studied the Google Chart API and i am not sure if there's a way.
Please share some code if available which will produce a hierarchical bar/ column charts.
Thanks

Comment: It's 100% possible, give me time to write an example up for you.

Comment: Thanks Raptus that will be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to do so using google charts visual api/google apps script.
As data looks to contain hierarchy under which the bars are constructed.

Comment: Well Come to SO. This should be in comment section. Read this on [how to write good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Saying this, you're pretty much saying to some of the best minds Google has that they haven't covered all bases with their API.

Comment: There's no question about their capabilities.This site is for finding the correct approach/answers to the challenges faced. It is requested to not to deviate from the track. Thanks